# How to render angular Universal in remote Tomcat server

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular6, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am able to create an angular universal app in my local system. But when I build in tomcat server, it is throwing error: port 80 - permission denied.(i m using Port 80 by default). What are the commands and steps to build the app for production?

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, Angular 14 Universal suggests to use [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/), which is a lightweight web server and can be easily run and deploy behind Nginx. For example:

```
PORT=9010 nohup node <your angular main.js> >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This command will host your Angular universal app in background at port 9010.

However, you can directly put `dist/<your app name>/browser` folder into Tomcat.